# How to run MySQL on OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mySQL using the binary (.dmg) available from their website. Installation seemed successful as I got an entry for mySQL in the System Preferences. Opening it shows mySQL server is running.

However, I cannot run it from the command prompt. It says `mysql: command not found`. Also, `which mysql` returns nothing. I'm not sure if I have to add a path or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to your PATH environment variable.

Execute in the Terminal:

`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add a path variable.

Try this:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

And always you can use a visual tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: Without putting the `export` line into `.bash_profile` or another shell startup file, the setting will be lost on reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I would say use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) then you can install it with

```
$ brew install mysql
```

Additional instructions can be obtained via

```
$ brew info mysql
```